# document.myform.checkbox.checked without a form

Tags: javascript, forms, getelementbyid

i know that what i mentioned on the question (above) isn't possible, but i have a problem here, i have double tripe and so on, forms inside a page, and i need to submit a form that gets all the data inside the previous forms.

WARNING: I started with javascript like 3 or 4 days ago, i am used to the server-side programming.

Let's see:

javascript checks if checkboxes are checked (Several of them):

```
function KeepCount() {

var NewCount = 0;

if (document.iphone3g.iphone3g1.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone3g.iphone3g2.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone3g.iphone3g3.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone3g.iphone3g4.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone3gs.iphone3gs1.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone3gs.iphone3gs2.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone3gs.iphone3gs3.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone3gs.iphone3gs4.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone4.iphone41.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone4.iphone42.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone4.iphone43.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (document.iphone4.iphone44.checked)
{NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

if (NewCount > 1){
    descontox = 20/100;
    valorx = (total.value * descontox).toFixed(2);
    valor.value  = (total.value - valorx).toFixed(2);
    }

if (NewCount <= 1){
    valor.value = ("");}
}
```

This tells me if a discount should be applied or not, if more than one checkbox is selected it will apply a 20% discount.

If you notice, i have several "if (document.iphone3g.iphone3g1.checked) { do something} that interacts with this:

```
    <div id="one" class="hiddenDiv">

            <div class="image">
                <img class="large" src="images/iphone3g.png" alt="iphone3g" width="141" height="141" />
            </div>
            <form name="iphone3g">
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3g1" value="50.00"> Vidro Partido<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3g2" value="59.00"> LCD Danificado<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3g3" value="80.00"> Substituir capa traseira<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3g4" value="38.00"> Botão Volume
            </form>
    </div>
            <div id="two" class="hiddenDiv">

            <div class="image">
                <img class="large" src="images/iphone3gs.png" alt="iphone3g" width="141" height="141" />
            </div>
    <form name="iphone3gs">
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3gs1" value="60"> Vidro Partido 3GS<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3gs2" value="69"> LCD Danificado 3GS<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3gs3" value="89"> Substituir capa traseira 3GS<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3gs4" value="45"> Botão Volume3GS

    </form>
    </div>
            <div id="three" class="hiddenDiv">

            <div class="image">
                <img class="large" src="images/iphone4.png" alt="iphone3g" width="141" height="141" />
            </div>
    <form name="iphone4">
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone41" value="169"> Vidro/LCD Partido<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone42" value="99"> Substituir capa traseira<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone43" value="79"> Botão Volume<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone44" value="76"> Botão Home

    </form>
    </div>
```

I have more than 3 of those, what can i do to solve the question? i need to submit these data to a php file.

Comment: you might try correcting the question title, to get better responses

Comment: If you need to have all of the forms submiitted at once, you should not be using multiple forms. You should just be using one with properly named form elements.

Comment: epascarello, i want not to use so many forms, but how can i check if checkboxes are checked without using forms? That is the question...

Comment: Do you really have multiple forms? It sounds like you are confused. In your example you have exactly one form that contains multiple form elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, this could be done very succinctly.

```
// select all checked checkboxes with name attribute that starts with 'iphone'
var NewCount = $("input[name^='iphone']:checked").length;

if (NewCount > 1){
    descontox = 20/100;
    valorx = (total.value * descontox).toFixed(2);
    valor.value  = (total.value - valorx).toFixed(2);
    }

if (NewCount <= 1){
    valor.value = ("");}
}
```

EDIT: souza -- It appears based on your comments that you have already solved the issue by using a single form element. However, you would be wise to use a more generic approach like the one above, or the one posted by mrtsherman. Checking each individual input element by name will lead to a code maintenance nightmare.

It would require updating both the your markup and your javascript every time a new iPhone version and/or carrier, platform comes around. A more generic approach would allow you to simply add a new checkbox to the markup using the same naming convention and your javascript will simply handle it without the need to make any changes to the code.

Comment: Mad Man Moon, thank you very much for your tip, it was very useful, and from now on i will try to grab some information about libraries like jquery.
EDIT: I am using your code, is working like a charm. I am very new to JS and i can't understand how your code is using the jQuery library. Can you explain me the code please? I don't want just to use it but understand it. Thank you very much. Kind Regards, Hélder Sousa.

Comment: Souza -- you need to include a script tag that references the jquery library (available from many content delivery networks) on your page. So, add this as the first line in your <head> section:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: I know that Mad Man Moon, i just wanted to know how the script knows when it needs to use the library. Let me try to explain, in php if i need to use a database i need to connect to it, how in JS the script you gave me knows he needs to go get information to the library? Using the $ simbol?

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery. Easy to use for something like this. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/umhrg/) with it working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
      var checked = $("input:checked").length;
      alert(checked);
   });
});
```

Comment: I am really sorry for my mistake, i wanted to insert less code than 
every of it, now the code is complete, like in my form.
Mine works like a charm, but is using 3 forms to work properly :(

Comment: Hey guys, the solution was simple, i didn't knew that between the <form> tags you could use so much html code. Solved the problem