# Detecting when more than one checkbox is checked in a form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, browser

i'm getting nuts with this, i got a lame function to work but is not compatible with all browsers:

javascript code:

```
        function KeepCount() {

        var NewCount = 0;

        if (document.FormName.iphone3g1.checked)
        {NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

        if (document.FormName.iphone3g2.checked)
        {NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

        if (document.FormName.iphone3g3.checked)
        {NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

        if (document.FormName.iphone3g4.checked)
        {NewCount = NewCount + 1;}

        if (NewCount == 2){
            valor.value  = total.value - (total.value*20/100);}

        if (NewCount <= 1){
            valor.value = 0;
        }

        }
```

html part:

```
<input onclick="clickCh(this);return KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3g1" value="50.00"> Vidro Partido<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);return KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3g2" value="59.00"> LCD Danificado<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);return KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3g3" value="80.00"> Substituir capa traseira<br />
    <input onclick="clickCh(this);return KeepCount();" type="checkbox" name="iphone3g4" value="38.00"> Botão Volume
```

Well, this applies a disccount using chrome and firefox, but i don't really like the code anyway.

**I know there are a lot of experts here, can some of you help me, please?** I would be very thankful

Comment: I would not calculate and give discounts in javascript.  That is very much a server side function not a client side function. (What kind of discounts could I give myself with some creative client side manipulation?)

Comment: If this is for an ecommerce site or something involving real money, its a very bad idea to handle this kind of discount/price logic entirely client side. That said, you may be doing some validation server side as well, which would be *strongly* recommended.

Comment: `javascript:valor.value = -15; // Send me $15!`

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096600/document-myform-checkbox-checked-without-a-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jquery, you  could do something like

```
 if($('#productDiv input:checked').length >= 2) ...
```

That way you don't have manually code each checkbox. Instead wrap them all in some div, or give them some unique css class, in which case you'd select with `$('input.myProduct:checked')`, and its easy to get the count.(BTW, you probably want `NewCount >= 2`, not `==`)

As @John Weldon said though, it's fine to calculate this client side if you want to display it in the browser, but you MUST verify that all the prices are proper on the server side once you receive the order, otherwise I could give myself a 100% discount, etc...

Comment: Jesse Cohen, i can't vote (Don't know why) but i tested your solution and works great, so, thank you very much.
About the client-side discount, its just a number, we will check what products the client wants by seeing wich checkboxes he selected, then we will calculate the discount ourselfes.
Thank you very much, i love StackoverFlow :D